# error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve path when I run npm run build on netlify. files are not received

Tags: reactjs, build, netlify

Could not resolve path when I run npm run build on netlify. files are not received even though it runs fine on localhost

[this is my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xQa7.png)
[This is my app.jsx file, all of the above import code has errors so it's not a typo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOikW.png) 
[i suspect the code is not receiving the jsx file and here is my vite.config.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zjzqP.png)

i hope someone having the same error or understanding the error can help me, everything works fine localhost, and no typos or wrong file path

Comment: Can please put the error message and code, suitable formatted as code, in the post. Doing this helps other immediately see what the issue is and possible select and query relevant text.  Most readers will not look at image links in posts.